How to stop GTest from using main within object archive?
I have a tests directory where I am trying to run unit tests from functions created within the src directory. The source directory creates an object library which links with the src executable as well as the tests executable. Each directory has a CMakeLists.txt file. My file structure looks like:
myproj
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- src
|   |-CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- main.cpp
|   |-- file1.cpp
|   `-- file2.cpp
`-- tests
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    `-- mytests.cpp

The problem is that when I run my test, it calls the main function of the program within the src directory instead of gtest because one of the object files is main.cpp.o. I.e., it runs the program and not the test. So I thought to remove the main.cpp.o from the list of targets and link the test against that, but this doesn't seem to be working.
Here is my tests/CMakeList.txt file.
list(FILTER $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib>
    EXCLUDE REGEX ".*main.cpp.o$")

add_executable(mytest
    mytests.cpp)

target_include_directory(mytest
    PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src)
    
target_link_directories(mytest
    PUBLIC
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib>
        GTest::Main)
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src)(

add_test(mytest mytest)

Should this work or am I going about it the right way?
Update:
I changed the REGEX to ".*main\\.cpp\\.o$" to no avail.

Thanks - fixed typo. Looking into escape.

Added update to OP. Also tried just using ".main." since there's only one file in this list called main, but this didn't catch it either.

A generator expression $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib> is expanded only after the end of configuration process. That is, applying list for it has a little sense: you are filtering the literal $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib>, not its value.

Attempt to filter objects in the OBJECT library looks as a bad idea. Instead, maintain two object libraries: the one which includes only main.cpp, and the other which includes the rest of sources. When compile src executable, use both these libraries. When compile test executable, use only the second library.

@Tsyvarev - If you'd like to make that an answer, I'll mark it. Worked for me.
